# MemberNumber field in MemberPlan object not searchable

Tags: search, externalid, salesforce-classic, global-search, health-cloud

We have installed Health Cloud and there is an object named Member Plan. This object is searchable in setup (like all the standard objects). We created a custom external ID text field in this object, but we cannot search in global search using this field. Checked the Search Settings and this object is not present. Also tried looking for documentations but seen nothing. Any idea how to make it searchable in global search?

Comment: Is there a tab for that? I remember that custom object should have a tab to be searchable.

Comment: yes there is a tab, it's on Default On

Comment: That's strange.  I recommend opening a case with Salesforce support.